# Why does not Fubini's theorem apply to this double integral?

Tags: integration, measure-theory

Consider the space $ (\Omega \times \Omega,\mathcal{A}\otimes \mathcal{A}, \mu \times \nu) $, where $ \Omega=\mathbb{N} $, $ \mathcal{A} $ is the collection of all subsets of $ \mathbb{N} $ and $ \nu=\mu $ denotes the counting measure, i.e., $ \mu(A)=\nu(A)=\# A $ for all $ A\in \mathcal{A} $. Consider the function $ f:\Omega\times\Omega\to\mathbb{R} $ given by:
$$ f(x,y)=
\begin{cases}
x &\text{if } y=x \text{, } x\in \mathbb{N}\\
-x &\text{if } y=x+1 \text{, } x\in \mathbb{N}\\
0 &\text{otherwise}
\end{cases} $$

I compute two integrals:
\begin{align*}
\iint f \text{ } d\mu\text{ }  d\nu&=\int\left( \int f_y d\mu \right) d\nu\\
&=\int\left( \sum_{x=1}^{\infty}f_y(x) \right) d\nu\\
&=\int\left( f_y(1)+\cdots+f_y(y-2)+f_y(y-1)+f_y(y)+f_y(y+1)+\cdots \right) d\nu\\
&=\int\left( 0+\cdots+0-(y-1)+y+0+\cdots \right) d\nu\\
&=\int 1 d\nu\\
&=\sum_{y=1}^{\infty} 1 \\
&=\infty.
\end{align*}
and
\begin{align*}
\iint f \text{ } d\nu\text{ }  d\mu &=\int\left( \int f_x d\nu \right) d\mu\\
&=\int\left( \sum_{y=1}^{\infty} f_x(y) \right) d\mu\\
&=\int\left( f_x(1)+\cdots +f_x(x-1)+f_x(x)+f_x(x+1)+f_x(x+2)+\cdots \right) d\mu\\
&=\int\left( 0+\cdots +0+x+-x+0+\cdots \right) d\mu\\
&=\int 0 d\mu\\
&=\sum_{x=1}^{\infty}(0)\\
&=0+0+0+\cdots\\
&=0.
\end{align*}

Why is not
$$ \iint f \text{ } d\mu\text{ }  d\nu = \iint f \text{ } d\nu\text{ }  d\mu$$
in accordance with Fubini's theorem? Has it something to do with $f$ not being in $L^1(\mu\times\nu)$? If so, how can I show that this is the case?

Comment: Indeed, did you try to evaluate $\iint|f|d\mu d\nu$? What happened when you did?

Comment: I am not intierly sure about how to do that. Is $ |f(x,y)| $ simply the following?
$$ |f(x,y)|=\begin{cases}
x &\text{if } y=x \text{, } x\in \mathbb{N}\\
x &\text{if } y=x+1 \text{, } x\in \mathbb{N}\\
0 &\text{otherwise}
\end{cases} $$

Comment: And is $ \iint|f|d\mu d\nu $ this?
$$\begin{align*}
 \iint|f(x,y)|d\mu d\nu&=\int\left( \int |f_y| d\mu \right) d\nu\\
&=\int\left( \sum_{x=1}^{\infty}|f_y(x)| \right) d\nu\\
&=\int\left( 0+\cdots+0+(y-1)+y+0+\cdots \right) d\nu\\
&=\int (2y-1) d\nu\\
&=\sum_{y=1}^{\infty} (2y-1) \\
&=\infty.
\end{align*} $$

Comment: Fubini's theorem fails because $$\iint|f(x,y)|d\mu d\nu=\infty,$$ 
is that right?

Comment: Is $\iint|f(x,y)|d\mu d\nu<\infty$ the same as $f\notin L^1(\mu\times\nu)$?

Comment: Yes, that is correct. Except it would be more correct to say that Fubini's theorem doesn't apply since $\iint \lvert f(x,y)\rvert\,d\mu\,d\nu = +\infty$, rather than that it fails.

Comment: In this particular case, $\iint \lvert f(x,y)\rvert\,d\mu\,d\nu = +\infty$ is exactly the same as $f \notin L^1(\mu\times \nu)$, since all functions are $\mathcal{A}\otimes \mathcal{A}$-measurable. In other situations, $f\notin L^1(\mu\times\nu)$ might also be due to non-measurability of $f$.